# WordPress API functions not working at AJAX functions.php call

Tags: ajax, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am trying to show subcategories of a category in WordPress using AJAX: when I select a main category, there is a call to WP Ajax and the result is used in showing the subcategories.

So far, I have the client-side code that works when not calling a WP function (this code is in a theme page):

```
jQuery('#cat-location-main').change(function () {
    var optionSelected = jQuery(this).find('option:selected');
    var valueSelected = optionSelected.val();
    var textSelected = optionSelected.text();
    console.log(valueSelected);
    jQuery.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: ajaxurl,
      data: {
            action: 'myajax-get-subcat',
            category: valueSelected,
            // send the nonce along with the request
            categoryNonce: '<?php echo wp_create_nonce( 'myajax-get-subcat-nonce' );?>'
      },
      success: function(data, textStatus, jjqXHR) {
          console.log(data);
      },
      dataType: 'json'
    });
 });
```

And I have this in the functions.php:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_myajax-get-subcat', 'myajax_get_subcat');

function myajax_get_subcat() {
    $nonce = $_POST['categoryNonce'];
    $main_category = $_POST['category'];

    if (!wp_verify_nonce($nonce, 'myajax-get-subcat-nonce'))
        die ( 'Busted!');

    if(function_exists('wp_dropdown_categories')==true) {
        echo 'true';
    } else {
        echo 'false';
    }
    wp_dropdown_categories('taxonomy=category&selected=1&echo=1&orderby=NAME&order=ASC&hide_empty=0&hide_empty=0&hierarchical=1&depth=1&id=cat-location-secondary&child_of='.$main_category);  
    exit;
}
```

Now I get a "true" on the client side when commenting **wp_dropdown_categories** line, and I get absolutely nothing when I uncomment that line (PHP crash). Nothing in php error log (WAMP setup).

Also, not working even if I add `require_once(__DIR__.'/../../../wp-load.php');` but it works if I use GET in browser (for the functions.php).
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

My problem was because I do not return a json object but an html (actually mixed text and html), and you set jQuery to validate that the response is json, which it isn't.